# Construct smooth function in a compact planar domain with given boundary conditions

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Consider a compact domain with piecewise smooth boundary, for example, consider a triangle domain:($\triangle ABC$), how to construct a smooth function $F(x,y)$, such that
\begin{align}
F(x,y)=\begin{cases}f_1(x,y)\in C^1(\mathbb{R^2}),\quad (x,y)\in AB\\
f_2(x,y)\in C^1(\mathbb{R^2}),\quad (x,y)\in CB\\
f_3(x,y)\in C^1(\mathbb{R^2}),\quad (x,y)\in AC.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
And $f_j$ are compatiable at $A,B,C$. In one dimension case, we can easily construct a smooth funtion given boundary value at end point, my question is how to generalize it to higher dimensional?

Comment: Is that smooth up to boundary? It seems more conditions on $f_1, f_2, f_3$ are needed.

Comment: @ArcticChar yes , $F$ is smooth up to the boundary.  I guess the only issue is the points $A,B,C$. if the boundary is smooth, then we can use the [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function)